# iTunes Store Operation Failed ERROR ITMS-90396: "Invalid Icon.with an alpha channel. Icons should not have an alpha channel."

Tags: ios, apple-watch, alpha, xcode9, channel

iOS 11 and Xcode 9.0 I have get following error when upload watch app on iTunes.

> iTunes Store Operation Failed ERROR ITMS-90396: "Invalid Icon. The
>   watch application 'MyApplication.app/Watch/myApp WatchKit App.app'
>   contains an icon file 'Icon Image-AppIcon-watch-86x86@2x.png' with an
>   alpha channel. Icons should not have an alpha channel."

[image]

Comment: and you dont know how to remove alpha from image?

Comment: yes i did not know how to solve this error.

Comment: remove alpha from your image

Comment: How can i remove alpha on image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this issues with Xcode 9.0.1. trying to upload App on the App store. So I can

Assets.xcassets -> WatchAppIcon

- Open your `WatchIcon.appiconset AppIcon86x86@2x.png` in Preview
- Export it unchecking alpha channel from it
- Now upload watch app on iTunes store

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put a white background on the image. The app icon is, I guess transparent in nature, so iTunes does not accept it. So please make sure by putting a white background on the app icon.

Thanks